# Creating multiple Objects with datetime for a specific time period

Tags: c#, date, datetime, unity-game-engine

I give my user the option to set a startdate and an enddate for an event. I want the user to have the option to generate the event every week between the start date and the enddate.

```
[Serializable]
public class LectureDateTime
{
public long? id;
public DateTime startTime;
public DateTime endTime;

public LectureDateTime()
{
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int weeks = (date1 - date2).TotalDays / 7;
```

Generate weeks count and then just do

```
    var list = new List<DateTime>();
    foreach(int week for weeks){
        list.Add(date1 + TimeSpan.FromDays(7 * week);
    }
```

In the list you will have all weeks between two dates